# OpenCV Project won't work on 64bit Win7 but on 32bit it works

Tags: opencv, dll, 32bit-64bit

I have the same c++ DLL project which is configured to be a 32-bit application in Visual Studio 2012. I'm using OpenCV 2.4.0, the 32-bit build and the matching static lib files.
Whenever I try to use the DLL on a second project, on a 64-bit machine, it fails ( the second project is also 32-bit), BUT when i run it on a 32bit machine, it runs fine.

The error i get on the 64-bit machine happens exactly when i try to load the DLL which uses OpenCV, and here it is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in TheApp.exe
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'TheDll.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module
>   could not be found.

The DLL is placed into the x86 folder from the current working directory, and it is referenced from there.

Comment: It doesn't matter what your OS architecture is, My both computers are 64bit but using OpenCV 32bit is always fine for me, Can you be more specific? It could be something missing like the dll files aren't put in the same folder where the executable is placed

Comment: Just some things to try...
Try with referencing with absolute path to DLL, print out cwd from your application, just for test. Open "TheDll.dll" in Dependency Walker, and check if some of dependent libraries are really missing.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys, but i actually fixed it.
I don't know what i was doing wrong so I reset all the project configuration, and just made sure that all dll's are where they should be.And I also used the <probing privatePath="somePath" /> tag, in the App.config file, and made sure that the architectures were all the same.